# Rails Model Association for a Podcast directory (Polymoprhic or HABTM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, model-associations, podcast

I'm creating an app that will be a directory for podcast/radio shows (mainly, for shownotes of each show). I'm stuck on how to model the People in this app, mainly because a person can be *both* a guest on many different episodes (within many different shows), but can also be a host (someone who is featured on every episode of a given show).

Example: Marco Arment is the host of the show "Build and Analyze", but may appear as a guest on occasional other podcasts (such as "The Gruber Talk Show" or "This Week in Tech").

My data model so far is shown below (focusing on the host/guest episode/show relationships). I'm not sure how to approach the Person/Guest/Host modeling, though I am sure I want to keep the roles of "Guest" and "Host" as separate items within the app.

```
Episode
  title:string
  has_many :guests

Show
  title:string
  has_many :hosts

Host
  show_id:integer
  person_id:integer
  belongs_to :show

Guest
  episode_id:integer
  person_id:integer
  belongs_to :episode

People
  name:string
  # ???
```

Should I just get rid of the "host" and "guest" models, and instead determine these rolls based on whether the Episodes or Shows are inquiring about the People associated with them? Remember, a "Show" can only have hosts and an "Episode" can only have guests –– but guests and hosts are always People (name, biography, twitter handle, etc).

Thanks. I explored polymorphic association and has_many :through and am not sure which to use, if either.

**UPDATE #1**

After sleeping on this, I had some better ideas about how to handle it in the morning. Similar to @Emm's response below, it seems natural that "Host" and "Guest" should simply be some quality of a Person via a separate model. Here is my new thinking on the model structure, which I setup before seeing any of the responses below.

The key difference here is that "Appearanceship" model would have a "role" column (string), where I could set if the person_id associated with that row was a "guest" or "host" for that row's episode_id or show_id.

```
class Appearanceship
  # person_id:integer
  # episode_id:integer
  # show_id:integer
  # role:string
  belongs_to :people
  belongs_to :episodes
  belongs_to :shows
end

class Person
  # name, bio, profile pic, twitter name, etc
  has_many :appearanceships
  has_many :episodes, :through => :appearanceships
  has_many :shows, :through => :appearanceships
end

class Episode
  # title, summary, date recorded, mp3 URL, web URL, etc
  has_many :appearanceships
  has_many :people, :through => :appearanceships
end

class Show
  # title, description, web URL, RSS URL, etc
  has_many :appearanceships
  has_many :people, :through => :appearanceships
end

class Network
  # e.g., "NPR", "5by5", "Mule Radio Syndicate", "Revision3"
  # title, description, web URL, etc
  has_many :shows
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only talking about two different models so I'd keep it simple. Let's combine `People`, `Host`, and `Guest` into `Person`; and let's combine `Episode` and `Show` into `Podcast`. You can define role differences between a host and a guest elsewhere.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :biography, :twitter
  has_many :podcasts
  has_many :podcasts, :through => :roles
end

class Podcast < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  has_many :persons
  has_many :persons, :through => :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :variety
  belongs_to :podcast
  belongs_to :person
end
```

And store in `variety` in `Role` the type of relationship between `Person` and `Podcast`. That could be a string like `"host"` or `"guest"`, or you could even make another model called `Variety` to manage that (and thus storing `variety_id` instead of `variety` in `Role`).

Answer (score 0):

show has many users through hosts

show has many episodes

episode has many users through guests

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shows, :through => :show_hosts
  has_many :show_hosts

  has_many :episodes, :through => :show_guests
  has_many :show_guests
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The better choice will be not to have Host and guest separate, the Guest can be defined as self-refrential relationship using HABTM.

your model definition will look something like this,

```
class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :guest, 
      :join_table => 'guests' #This is HABTM join table that you will have to create
      :foreign_key => 'host_id'
      :association_foreign_key => 'guest_id'
      :class_name => 'Host'


#The migration will look like this,
def change
  create_table :guests :id => false do |t|
    t.integer :host_id,  :null => false
    t.integer :guest_id, :null => false
  end
  add_index :guests, [:host_id, :guest_id]
end
```